# Not a statement

Tags: java

I am learning from a book to code with java. It gives an example of a guessing game and gives the code. I wanted to keep it as a reference. But I keep getting an error. And it might be the way I typed it cause I am reading it off a kindle and it kinda got a little messed up.

There are many errors like this, but none like mine. I am trying to make a guessing game, but I keep getting this error:

GuessingGame.java:17: not a statement
                    (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessingGame
{
    static Scanner sc = new
Scanner(System.in);
    public static void
main(String[] args)
    {
    bolean keepPlaying = true;
    System.out.println("Let's play a guessing game!");
    while (keepplaying)
    {
        bolean validInput;
        int number, guess;
        String answer;
        // Pick a random number = 
    (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        // Get the guess
        System.out.print("What do you think it is? ");
        do
        {
            guess = sc.nextInt();
            validInput = true;
            if ((guess < 1) || (guess > 10))
            {
                System.out.print
                    ("I said between 1 and 10. "
                    + "Try again: ");
                validInput = false;
            }
        }while (!validInput);
        // Check the guess
        if (guess == number)
            System.out.println(
        "You're right!");
        else
            System.out.println(
        "You're wrong! " + "The number was " + number);
        // Play again?
        do
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlay again? (Yes or No)");
            answer = sc.next();
            validInput = true;
            if (asnwer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
            else if (answer.egualsIgnoreCase("No")-
                keepPlaying = false);
            else
                        validInput = false;
        } while (!validInput);
    }
    System.out.println("\nThank you for playing!");
}
```

}

Comment: What do yo think `(int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;` should do as it is? And why do you think that?

Comment: What do you do with the expression `(int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1`?

Comment: you're doing a math operation and a casting on that operation... and then never assigning the result of any of that to a variable, so the result just... "hangs" there...

Comment: If you fixed your formatting, you would find the other half of the statement on the line above...

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question? The guy is just trying to learn to write Java.

Comment: What's the -2 for?  The question provides code and clearly expresses the problem...

Comment: I partially fixed the downvote. The question is completely legitimate

Answer (score 6):

It's true, `(int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;` isn't a statement. And Java, unlike some other langauges, doesn't allow just expressions as statements.

I think the word `number` in the comment above belongs on the line:

Not:

```
// Pick a random number = 
(int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

But:

```
// Pick a random number
number = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

(There's already an `int number;` above, so the variable is already declared and everything.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the value you are computing in the statement to a variable. 
IN your case it is the variable number.

```
number = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `number` variable being referenced but never created. I assume that this is the variable that needs to take the correct number. Change:

```
(int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

to

```
number = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

Comment: @Quirliom: Yes, but the version of hexa's answer that I was commenting on was redeclaring it. He's since removed the redeclaration.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `(int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;` just gets a random number as an `int` but doesn't store it as anything. Try doing this.

```
number = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```